# Is <th> only semantically different from <td>?

Tags: html

Their looks are the same actually

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since there is a semantic difference most browsers also bold and center the contents of a `<th>` tag.
This is irrelevant if you are using a reset stylesheet, but there is a presentational difference by default.

Answer (score 3):

No, generally unformatted text in a th table header element will be bold. But you should use CSS to style the way you want them to appear. If you use something like [Yahoo Reset](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/reset/), then they will just be a semantic difference. To avoid cross-browser styling difference I recommend using something like Yahoo Reset which removes all browser default styling from most elements.